# What code is user mode code and what code is kernel mode code?

Tags: c, operating-system, programming-languages

I am having a question for myself while taking operating system course.

If I type in any C code to my text editor or though IDE and execute it with the compiler
it translates the code into machine code.

Then I would guess if I run the program, the OS will allocate a memory address to the code which is done by kernel code.

And if there was IO interrupt typed into my code, the kernel code executes.

And so...which bit is the user mode code then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ordinary course of events, any code you write is 'user mode code'.  Kernel mode code is executed only when you execute a system call and the control jumps from your user code to the operating system.

Obviously, if you're writing kernel code, or loadable kernel modules, then things are different — that code will be kernel mode code.  But most people most of the time are only writing user mode code.

Comment: so you mean, writing any sorts of application programs are mostly user mode? or can you give me a clear definiion of user mode

Comment: All of what you write is user mode.  When you make a system call — say `getpid()` or `read()` — the code you write is user mode code, right up to the moment when the system call executes the switch to kernel mode.  The (prewritten) code in the kernel then takes over for a while, and ultimately returns to the user mode with the appropriate actions having been taken;

Comment: so kernel code will be allcation of memory to my application program and scheduling etc and when is scheduled to the resouces than it is all usermode code not referering some system calls like IO interupt for instance scanf()

Comment: Yes, when your code requests memory, it makes a system call to request extra memory.  Not every call to `malloc()` results in a system call, of course; the C library normally tries to minimize the number of calls necessary by allocating more memory than absolutely necessary on the first call, and using the extra on subsequent calls.  The C library is user mode code, too, though.  And yes, the kernel deals with pre-emptive process scheduling, interrupts, disk management, etc.  But when your code is not making system calls, that is user mode code.  All of `scanf()` is user mode code.

Comment: but scanf() does call subroutines which is systemcall right? because its funtion is to call IO request

Comment: When `scanf()` needs data from the input file descriptor, it makes a `read()` system call, or its equivalent, yes.  But that system call is user mode code, right up to the switch into kernel mode.  And then the kernel executes, and returns to `scanf()`, which continues its merry way in user mode.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel mode versus user mode actually reflects how the processor is running.

With modern operating systems, code only runs (with the processor) in kernel mode if it is trusted by the operating system, and all other code runs in user mode.

The functional difference, under modern operating systems, is that kernel mode code runs in a single (virtual) address space that represents all system resources, so all functions in kernel mode can affect each other directly.   For example, all actions by a kernel mode driver can directly affect functioning of the operating system itself and of any other kernel mode driver.   (The specifics implementation details vary somewhat between operating system types, for example between windows, linux, BSD, etc but the basic principles are the same)

Which means that, if you are writing code that will execute within the internal workings of the operating system or within a kernel mode driver, then it might be said to be kernel mode code.   Otherwise, it will be user-mode code.   Code that attempts some action that can only be executed in kernel mode will be prevented from doing so by the processor itself, unless the processor itself is in kernel mode.  The operating system itself mediates when the processor enters kernel mode, which is why code need to be recognised by the operating system (or installed, in the case of kernel mode drivers) in order to do things that can only be done in kernel mode.    User mode code can't arbitrarily escalate the processor to kernel mode, without the help of some code that is already recognised by the operating system.

Practically, modern operating systems also supply a set of functions (e.g. in an API) that can be called from user mode.   A lot of those functions are, themselves, executed solely in user mode.   Some, however, result in the the processor being switched into kernel mode to perform some specific actions, and then the processor is switched back to user mode by the time control returns to the caller.  Which code, within the OS itself, executes in user mode or kernel mode depends both on the design of the operating system and administrative settings (e.g. only suitably privileged users (aka administrators) can, for example, install kernel mode drivers).